# React-bootstrap switch not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm trying to incorporate Formik and React-bootstrap.

It's going as expected except the switch component.

Here is my function for rendering the switch:

```
function ReactSwitch(props){
    return(
        <>
            <Col md={props.col}>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Check 
                        type="switch"
                        id={props.id}
                        name={props.name}
                        label={props.label}
                        checked={props.checked}
                        onChange={props.onChange}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>
        </>
    );
}
```

And here is my initialization for Formik:

```
const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          wflow_switch: false
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        },
});
```

Note that when I change the type from switch to checkbox, it displays a checkbox but still no label. What am I doing wrong? I'm still learning React so any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need to use `state` and enable [enablereinitialize](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean)

**Try this:**

```js
export default function FormSwitch() {
  // add checked state
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

  const { handleSubmit, values } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      // initial value is set 'false' by state 
      switch: checked
    },
    // Control whether Formik should reset the form if initialValues changes
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
        setSubmitting(false)
      }, 400)
    }
  })
  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <ReactSwitch
        name="switch"
        label="Switch"
        id="switch"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      />
      <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

---

**Edit:** Different approach using [useField](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useField) with `<Formik>`

```js
import { Formik, useField } from "formik"
import { Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap"

const ReactSwitch = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [field, form] = useField(props)

  return (
    <Col md={props.col}>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Check
          type="switch"
          id={props.id}
          checked={field.value.checked}
          onChange={() => form.setFieldValue(props.name, !field.value)}
          {...field}
          {...props}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Col>
  )
}

export default function Switch() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        switch: false
      }}
      onSubmit={values => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))}
    >
      {formik => (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <ReactSwitch label="Switch" name="switch" id="switch" />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit useFormik-react-bootstrap-switch]

Comment: I see. But won't this defeat the purpose of Formik to control all changes? I'm sorry but I'm new to React.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you. I think no because we are using `useFormik` [Hook](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik#use-cases-for-useformik) here which actually used for creating a modified version of `<Formik>`. However, I updated the codeSandbox and used a different approach `useField` with `<Formik>` Please check it out.

Comment: Got it! Thank you @awran5